# "find" command but it stops going deep if it finds a directory starting with "."

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have to make a script that goes through a whole folder (`/home`, in my case).

I have to save all the files except the ones that start with `.`, and also, if I find a directory that starts with `.`, I don't have to care what's inside, I don't have to read it.

For the first part we use the command

```
for path in $(find /home \! -name ".*");do
```

where `path` is a variable that contains the path. But we don't know how to do the directory part.

I thought I'd cut the path through the `/` and then see if there's any `.`. In that case, have an `if` that does not save the file, but I don't know how to cut a string and save it in a variable and then go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for path in $(find /home -type d -name ".*" -prune -o -type f \! -name ".*" -print);do echo $path; done
```

Comment: Thanks, as i was waiting for someone to resolve my problem, i came up with the same code that u provided here except form -prune and that "-o" that i dont know what it is.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can *prune* all files starting with a `.`.

From the man page of GNU `find`:

> `-prune` True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it. If `-depth` is given, false; no effect. Because `-delete` implies `-depth`, you cannot usefully use `-prune` and `-delete` together.

You should not loop over the result from `find`. You will get unexpected results if you have filenames with spaces or newlines. 
Use `xargs` or `-exec`, e.g.

```
find /home -path "*/.*" -prune -o -print0 | xargs -0I{} sh -c 'echo "doing something with $1"' sh {}
```

or

```
find /home -path "*/.*" -prune -o -exec sh -c 'for i; do echo "doing something with $i"; done' sh {} +
```

The `-prune` part removes all filenames (files and directories) starting with a dot and does not descend into directories starting with a dot.
All other filenames are printed with a NUL character instead of a newline (`-o -print0`) and piped to `xargs` or a shell script is executed with your action (as few times as possible).

To save all filenames into a file:

```
find /home -path "*/.*" -prune -o -print > allfiles.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and thanks for explaining the comands you use, but, there are som things on your code that i dont understand yet, so i used the answer provided by DamianK and that worked perfectly for me. Also it was very usefull to learn about "-prune", that was the command missing on my code to work.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do something like that:

```
for path in $(find . -type f | egrep -v '/\.[^\/]+\/'); do
...
```

Note that you may have to take extra steps if some of your files have spaces in their names.